# Intersection of half angle with centroid

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, centroid

I am in calculus 2 and I recently came up with a question.  With the formulas f(x)=n and g(x)=x^2 is there a value for n in which the half angle between the intersection of the parabola and the horizontal line that intersects with the centroid.  I am linking to a desmos that illustrates what I am trying to say.  Where do I have to put f(x) such that h(x) intersects with the centroid.  https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pdrwcv4v0y

Thanks for any help you may be able to provide.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by centroid here?

Comment: So is there a line that bisects where the parabola meets the horizontal line that then intersects the center of mass of that shape.  Which would result in half the area being on each side of the bi-secting line.

Comment: The parabola extends to infinity on the side it 'opens up'. Wouldn't the center of mass be infinitely far away in some sense (while on the axis of symmetry)?